# How to extract the first row in a DynamoDB table?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using (AWS) `DynamoDB` for the first time, so my question is rather basic.

I have set up a table (myTable) containing one field (theField) and I am able to fill it up one record at a time.

Here is what I want to do: *make a query to extract the first element of the sorted table*. I guess it could hardly be simpler.

This is my code, based on what I could find in the AWS documentation and on some example from the net:

```
    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    queryExpression.scanIndexForward = false
    queryExpression.limit = 1

    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.query(myTable.self, expression: queryExpression) {
       (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        if output != nil {
            // Process the output.
        }
    }
```

When I run this code I get the error message below:

```
The request failed. Error: Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" 
UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException, message=Either the KeyConditions or 
KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.})
```

First what is this KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression business?
The query is clear why do I need any condition?

Second, I of course tried to fill some dummy condition (based on what I could find on some other post) to see what happens, but it never worked.

Could someone tell me how I need to write queryExpression to do what I want?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, I think you can't get the so-called `first row`. The data in dynamodb is stored in partitions, which you can take it as different folders and each is specified by the `partition key`. You need to provide the key to decide which folder/partition it looks into, so there does not exist `first` row in the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You have no query criteria. For a query you need to provide at least the PartitionKey. Try a [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) instead of a query.

Comment: Thanks! I followed this suggestion of looking into a scan instead of a query and I made significant progress, though I do not yet get exactly what I want. I reformulated the question in a new post, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073808/getting-information-from-a-table-in-dynamodb

Comment: My answer solves the error from your question. Please consider marking this answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: No, your answer did not solve my problem. But it certainly was helpful and helped me move forward. This is why I up voted it, without ticking the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract first item from a dynamodb. Not with scan or query. You have to scan the table entirely or create a GSI with createdAt as hashKey/sortKey