# Getting information from a table in DynamoDB

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to find my way querying (scanning) a table in `DynamoDB`.
This is the code I have, almost working.

```
    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default(),
    scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.scan(MyTable.self, expression: scanExpression) {
        (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }

        if output != nil {
            print("Item count: \(output!.items.count)")
            for item in output!.items {
                let theItem = item as? MyTable
                print("theItem: \(theItem!._vcIdKey!)")
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I can see one item listed, while there are in reality seven in the table.

I want in fact one item, but I thought I would need to add this line for that (and I don't have to):

```
scanExpression.limit = 1
```

**Why is it so?**

The second problem is that I get the last element and I want to get the first.

**What do I need to change?**

A bit more information: I also tried the following code, with the very same result.

```
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.scan(VoChaAudioPost.self, 
                              expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: {
        (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in

        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
        } else if let output = task.result {
            print("items count: \(output.items.count)")
            for item in output.items /*as! VoChaAudioPost*/ {
                // Do something with item.
                print("item : \(item)")
            }
        }
        return()
    })
```

Comment: Can you follow this example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-dynamodb-objectmapper.html#perform-a-scan and compare?

Comment: I am trying to see that, but if I use it I get an error:

Cannot invoke 'continueWith' with an argument list of type '(block: (AWSTask<AnyObject>!) -> Any?)'

What should I do with that?

Comment: I changed:
"(task:AWSTask<AnyObject>!) -> Any? in"
 to: "(task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in"
 and it works (at least I get rid of the error).

Comment: Then when I run I get this:

[11291:4791952] Task <D5XXXXX-03AF-4D94-9047-0833344424>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001

[11291:4791956] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x155ecbb70]: 1:50 Err(50)

[11291:4791956] Task <D5XXXXX-03AF-4D94-9047-0833344424>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [1:50])

....

book : <MyApp.MyTable: 0x157609740> {

    "_xxIdKey" = "9A03387F-B76C-4495-AB22-FC8DAB9SS981";

    "_yyIdKey" = XYZ15248266777222119891;
    
}

Comment: It seems like something is crashing after the first item. That explains why I did not get more than one item.

Comment: Can you post how you are defining `MyTable` class? Are you using Swift 4.x or 3.2?

Comment: Yes, that was 2 days ago. Here is what happened, seeing that things were not working as I thought they should. I gave up and shut my computer down. The next day after booting, when I went to try again in order to figure out what could be wrong, all was working as expected. That was a happy news for me. But I am not able to explain to you why it so happened. I can only assume that by rebooting things go set up in a proper state (not a very good explanation). I am using Swift 4.1.